# Can anyone tell me what this expression denotes for bash sorting "sort -r -n -k5"

Tags: bash, sorting

Please explain me what does `-r -n -k5` means?

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter the name of the directory"
read file_name
if [ -d $filename ]
then
   ls -l $filename | sort -r -n -k5
else
  echo "Invalid directtroy"
fi
```

Comment: Doesn't `man sort` explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-r is to reverse the results

-n specifies numerical ordering

-k5 indicates it is comparing the entries in the 5th column